# vb6/ODBC : crash when browsing a recordset

Tags: oracle, vb6, odbc, oledb

I'm maintaining an old VB6 app which has a sort of built-in query feature.
That feature usually works good but it crashes when the user inputs particular queries. The crash is reproducible 100% of the time for a given query and happens exactly at the same place in the code.

On the line

```
toto = rcs.Fields(i)
```

, VB6 catches a blocking error from OLE-DB: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors" (execution error -214721778 (80040e21)

"i" is not out of bounds. Other columns exhibit the same problem. When breaking at the time it crashes, rcs.Fields(i + 1).Value is Null, rcs.Fields(i + 2).Value would raise the same error, and rcs.Fields(i + 3).Value has a non Null and valid value.
It seems not to be related to the number of results returned because I have tested select statements on other tables and they don't crash.
The error seem to be related to some columns, because removing some from the select (but only particular columns, of type date) prevent the app from crashing. It is not directly related to the total number of the columns (because things seem to work with a large number of columns, I have tested it).

The connection is opened as follow :

```
conn.ConnectionString = "uid=uidValue;pwd=pwdValue;DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};server=serverValue"
conn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
```

I have uploaded two ODBC logs, one with the content just before the crash (http://pastebin.com/PH1nQ2VC), and another (http://pastebin.com/AJqsYviQ) just after my connection is opened. There are some suspicious messages when the connection is opened but really it's hard to tell if they have anything to do with the error.

---

Query:

```
SELECT
 table_.someDateField -- type DATE
FROM
 table_actual_name table_
WHERE
 table_.someStringField LIKE '%5582%' -- type VARCHAR2 (10)

-- notes
--  someDateField can be NULL
--  someStringField can be NULL too (although that would make no sense and the actual database has 1 line with a NULL)
```

Comment: This error means you need to check conn.Errors to see the actual errors that have occurred to get detailed information.  See example at http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-is-this-multiple-step-ole-db-error.html

Comment: There are two items (silent errors) in conn.Errors as soon as the connection is opened.

1. Error Number -2147217887 (same as the one who pops up later but becomes blocking). Native error = 0. Source = Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers.

2. Error Number  -2147217887 (different description : the provider doesn't support this property). Source = ADODB.Connection

Despite these silent errors, the connection "seems to work" fine, it just happens to fail on some particular queries.

Comment: So what is the type of the field then?

Comment: It's a horrible error message isn't it. In my experience it is generally given when you are trying to put something into a column that won't fit. i.e. too many characters or too big a number

Comment: The field is of type Date. I am not writing anything in the recordset, just reading the values for the fields.

Comment: Whats the query that the user enters?

Comment: The query is pretty basic, see http://pastebin.com/ByjHkgaN

Comment: Can you add your log messages to the question, pastebin is no longer valid.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll try to find these logs and upload them again.